# Acceleration of a Mass on a Pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image: pulley system]

> Q: In the above diagram, two objects with their respective masses 5 kg and 3 kg are hung on a pulley with no friction. Find the magnitude of acceleration of the left object, the one with a mass of 5 kg. Assume g to be 10 m/s^2.

### My Working:

- I tried to find the net force that was acting on the 5 kg object first and then use Newton's second law to calculate its acceleration:

$\Sigma F = ma$

$50N - 30N = 20N$

$\therefore \text{an overall force of 20N downward is acting on the 5kg mass}$

$20N = 5a$

$a = 4 m/s^{2}$

### What the Marking Scheme Says:

> Since the two objects are connected, they always move together. Thus, we can treat them as one object with mass 8 kg. Hence, the forces acting on this "one" object are 50 leftward and 30 rightward. Assuming a convention of leftward being negative and rightward positive, by using Newton's second law:

$20 = 8a$

$a = 2.5 m/s^{2}$

---

I don't understand why the marking scheme treats the objects as one individual system; since we're only interested in the acceleration of the 5 kg load on the left, shouldn't we only consider that mass?

*question retrieved from https://brilliant.org/practice/newtons-second-law/?p=5 on 29/4/2021*